# Sound on open and slide to next page 3 seconds after action

Tags: android, html, ios

I am using `appmakerstudio` (app templates) a white label reseller of `Seattle Cloud` to create apps for Android and iOS. I am trying to create the following in HTML, and have some questions:

I am creating a kids letter find app which consists of tapping the `correct letter` to match a sound played (hear sound of `a`, user must tap the letter `a`). There will be 5 letters on the screen - only one of the 5 will be the `correct letter`. I would like to know how to do two things:

1. When the `.html` page first opens, how can I immediately play a sound (without the user having to take an action such as tapping)
2. After the sound has played, and the user has completed the required action (tapped the correct letter), a sound is generated (`correct!`) and after a 3 second wait, the page should auto slide to the next page.

If the user taps the incorrect letter (one that does not match the sound) then this generates a different sound and the page does not slide.  (I have the code for the sounds and the position of all of the letters already).

Here is my code so far (the sounds for the false letters are not the correct ones - they should all be the same).

```
<div style="text-align: left; float: left;">
    <a style="line-height: 21pt;" href="bgplayer-play://sounda.mp3">
        <img style="width: 19%;" src="flashcard-letter-a.png">
    </a>
</div>
<div style="text-align: right;">
    <a style="line-height: 21pt;" href="bgplayer-play://soundi.mp3">
        <img style="width: 19%;" src="flashcard-letter-i.png">
    </a>
</div>
<div style="text-align: left; float: left;"> <br>
    <a style="line-height: 21pt;" href="bgplayer-play://soundo.mp3">
        <img style="width: 19%;" src="flashcard-letter-o.png">
     </a>
</div>
<br>
<div style="text-align: right;">
    <a style="line-height: 21pt;" href="bgplayer-play://sounde.mp3">
        <img style="width: 19%;" src="flashcard-letter-e.png">
    </a>
</div>
<div style="text-align: center;"> <br>
    <a style="line-height: 21pt;" href="bgplayer-play://soundu.mp3">
        <img style="width: 19%;" src="flashcard-letter-u.png">
    </a>
</div>
<div style="text-align: center;"></div>
```

Comment: It seems your code was not pasted into the question, please click **edit** and you can paste it in the area where you left blank paragraphs. After that you can select all of it and click the `{}` from the edition menu for creating a code block.

Comment: Thank you Armfoot, I think I have entered it correctly now.  Is it visible?

Comment: It is appy :) though you can remove the ``` at the beginning and at the end of the block code, and just make sure all the code lines have four spaces before. This way it will identify the code's language and add colors. You can check the preview below (when editing, scroll down).

Comment: Thank you Armfoot ... my first post, so it's all very new :-)  Thank you for your help.